# Rows reposition to R in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, row

this is my outcome

[image]

But the rows of my table should be in this order:
0-14
15-28
29-42
....

Does anyone know how I can reposition these rows?

Ialready tried this:
vb_data[2:3,]
vb_data[c(2,3),]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse) 

df %>%
  arrange(parse_number(Periode))

# A tibble: 9 × 1
  Periode        
  <chr>          
1 Periode 0-14   
2 Periode 15-28  
3 Periode 29-42  
4 Periode 43-56  
5 Periode 57-70  
6 Periode 71-120 
7 Periode 121-180
8 Periode 181-240
9 Periode 241-300
```

Sample data

```
structure(list(Periode = c("Periode 0-14", "Periode 181-240", 
"Periode 241-300", "Periode 29-42", "Periode 43-56", "Periode 57-70", 
"Periode 71-120", "Periode 121-180", "Periode 15-28")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```